# Disable visual markdown editor on RStudio

Tags: rstudio, quarto

I'm working on a book project with [Quarto](https://quarto.org/) using RStudio 2022.02.2+485. Whenever I open a mardown `.qmd` file, RStudio automatically opens the file using the `Visual` markdown editor, what takes time to load. Even if I move to the `Source` pane, RStudio moves back again to `Visual` editor after and I make an edit to the file or whenever I open a new file.

Is there a way to disable the visual markdown editor on RStudio?

##### Rstudio version

> RStudio 2022.02.2+485 "Prairie Trillium" Release
> (8acbd38b0d4ca3c86c570cf4112a8180c48cc6fb, 2022-04-19) for Windows
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure the RStudio IDE to use or not Visual Editor by default. See Global Options
https://quarto.org/docs/visual-editor/options.html#global-options

On a per file basis, you can also set this in YAML

```yaml
editor: 
  mode: source
```

instead of

```yaml
editor: 
  mode: visual
```

So that the file always open in source mode.